# ManagedThreadFactory does not start the threads immediately

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-ee-7, java-threads

I am trying to migrate a legacy application to jee 7. As part of the deployment, we have a load on startup servelt which initializes few caches. Inturn these caches are used by other classes.

The legacy implementation initializes them sequentially. I am trying to initialize them in parallel to save deployment time.

I am using ManagedThreadFactory.newThread(callable).start();

The problem is, the threads are starting initializing after or by the end of the deployment. This is causing NPE in other classes depending on the caches.

Is there any way I can initialize the caches in parallel and once the caches are initialized, the rest of the deployment should proceed.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend a change to use a [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html).  You'd start your threads there but the difference is that you'd wait for them to come back in the `contextInitialized` method.  That way your servlets don't start until the servlet context is done initializing.  Honestly this is better than a startup servlet and works well before JEE 7.

The code would be something like:

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;

@WebListener
public class YourContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        // create the caches - you can still thread them for faster startup
        // but don't return until they are all initialized
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        // tear down the caches?
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I would still like to know why ManagedThreadFactory is not starting the threads immediately. Also, we will be replacing the startup Servlet with a startup singleton ejb later. So I don't think ServletContextListener is a choice for me.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think the threads aren't starting - it sounds like they are but other things are starting also.  Since a servlet that is run at startup is about the last thing that an app server does it's no wonder this is happening.  A startup EJB might work but ultimately you need to make sure it is done before the other tasks start - you are likely to need some sort of locking mechanism to prevent using the cache before it's ready.